# Previous Employer using my electronic Signature

Tags: employment, fraud, australia, signature

My previous employer uses an electronic signature program to execute General Tenancy Agreements. 
I have since left the company in August. However, it has been made known to me that the company is still using my login and signature (not just an electronic version, my actual signature) to execute these agreements.

They are known in the industry for having little respect for the legislation and laws (fraudulent invoices, employing unlicenced staff etc). Which is why I have left.

WHAT laws protect me and/or how can I make them stop? Pointing me to the legislation would be great. 
I am in QLD Australia - should I contact the OFT?

Comment: You need a lawyer and you need to contact the organisation responsible for investigating fraud. Especially in Australia, this is likely to carry fines if not jail time.

Comment: Saying "still using my login and signature" suggests a third party electronic signing service (Adobe Sign? DocuSign?). Log into your account and close it or contact the third party and have them close the account.

Comment: Having digital signatures and login credentials on file or used via the company's own system is quite possible, so the advice may be unhelpful, and this response does nothing to address the legal question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are specific laws that protect you. But you are not responsible for documents that carry your signature, you are responsible for documents that you sign. If you left in August, and there is a document which got your signature added in September, then it is quite obvious that you didn't sign it and you are not responsible.

On the other hand, it is usually the case that when someone signs, they are responsible, even if the signature is forged. So if they forge your signature to guarantee that some home is in a livable state, then they are responsible because they signed - even if the signature is yours. If they forge your signature to pretend that some qualified person checked the documents, and that hasn't happened, that would be a big problem for them if found it.

If some third party believes that some document represents the truth because they see your signature on it, and the contents of the document isn't actually true, and they lose money because of it, that is most likely fraud.  Committed by your ex-company, you have no responsibility whatsoever.